# Is there a way to use CSS to make a background image act like "cover" but at 120%?

Tags: html, css

The CSS value `background-size: cover` will stretch an image but retain its width to height ratio. However, it will only stretch it until the smallest side reaches 100% of the parent node's same side.

```
/* This is an image of 100px Wide x 50px Tall, so it'll 
   stretch to 100% of the window height and then scale the
   width larger to retain its width-to-height ratio.
 */
body
{
    background-image: url( "/images/test.png" );
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I want something that will do a cover but to some larger percentage, for example 130%. (I will be using this in a CSS keyframes animation to make the background image grow/shrink)

How would I do this?

Comment: I don't believe there is any such value - and I'm not even sure that `background-size` is a property that can be animated in all browsers. Could you create a separate element with the background (set to `cover`) and have your keyframe animation scaling that element with `transform: scale()`?

Comment: @JonUleis I think that will have to be the solution. I just wanted to know if there was a pure-CSS way.

Comment: Can you possibly use media queries for this? Check if the window is over a certain width and if it is, use a 130% for the width value of `background-size`. If it is under a certain width, set 130% for the height value of `background-size`. Or something like that...

Comment: @KodosJohnson i want to animate it growing larger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a pseudo element you can achieve something like that

*CSS animation has a browser support at +90%: [http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation_)*

```css
.bkg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bkg::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/400/nature/1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  animation: growme 5s forwards;
}
@keyframes growme {
  from {transform: scale(1);}
  to   {transform: scale(1.3);}  
}
```

```html
<div class="bkg"></div>
```

Grow and shrink

```css
.bkg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bkg::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20%;
  top: -20%;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/400/nature/1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  animation: shrinkme ease-in-out 10s infinite;
}
@keyframes shrinkme {
  0%   {transform: scale(1);}
  50%  {transform: scale(.72);}  
  100% {transform: scale(1);}
}
```

```html
<div class="bkg"></div>
```

Update based on comment where some browsers have issues animation pseudo elements, where one simply use a child element instead.

```css
.bkg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bkg div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/400/nature/1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  animation: growme 5s forwards;
}
@keyframes growme {
  from {transform: scale(1);}
  to   {transform: scale(1.3);}  
}
```

```html
<div class="bkg"><div></div></div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Wouldn't it be better for the pseudo width and height just 100%, so that it adapts to the base element ?

Comment: @LGSon any idea what the browser support is for using the pseudo element and giving it background and animating? http://caniuse.com/#search=keyfr seems to indicate there's issues animating pseudo elements in iOS Safari.

Comment: @DonRhummy Updated my answer with a 3:rd sample, using a child element instead of a pseudo

Comment: @DonRhummy And if you combine scale with a script, it will work down to IE9

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by applying the background-image to a psuedo element such as ::before that is positioned absolutely, and applying a scale transform to it.

Comment: any idea what the browser support is for that?

Comment: Transform is supported by all modern browsers and mostly a few versions back. Psuedo elements have been supported by all modern browsers for quite a few versions back. So, my assumption, is the combo of the two seems to be supported quite well. I have used this in real word production as it is compatible with current versions of modern browsers and 2 versions back on all as well.

Comment: Not support for transform, support for animating pseudo elements.

Comment: key frame animations are just a series of css calls, so any selector supported via CSS will be supported for key-frame animations. I would make sure to use browser-specific prefixes -webkit, -moz, and -o for sure.

The only limitations of psuedo elements I'm aware of, is that JS can't touch them